# How to create an 'All option' on Access Form dependent on another parameter?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
Grade             Name
______           ________
1                 John
2                 Jerry
3                 Jack
4                 Ben
5                 Bill
```

I have a form with two combo boxes named Combo1 and Combo2. Combo1 has three values-  1,2,3. Combo2 has three values - John, Jerry, All

And I set up the following query:

```
Select *  
From Persons
WHERE
        Persons.ID > Forms![Form1]![Combo1]
  AND (Persons.Name = Forms![Form1]![Combo2]) OR Forms![Form1]![Combo2]= 'All');
```

I want the user to be able to select either one or all the Names based on the criteria for Grades but it is not giving me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this minor modification:

```
Select 
    *  
From 
    Persons
WHERE
    Persons.ID > Forms![Form1]![Combo1]
    AND 
    (Persons.Name = Forms![Form1]![Combo2] OR Forms![Form1]![Combo2]= 'All');
```